# Mapbox navigation only using 2 of my waypoints in swift

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

Im trying to use 3 waypoints in mapbox navigation. When I run my app, It starts at the middle point, start rerouting, and then provides a route from my first to last point.

So to make things cleared. If i want to go from Los Angeles, stop at las  vegas, and then end my trip at San francisco. What it is doing is: Starts route at Las vegas, reroutes, and then starts route from los angeles to san francisco. This is my code.

```
            self.routeOptions = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: allPoints)


        Directions.shared.calculate(routeOptions!) { (session, result) in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        case .success(let response):
        guard let route = response.routes?.first else{
        return
        }

            self.route = route

            }
        }
```